# how to match database retrieved data with input values in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, regex, cakephp

i would like to search a database table for data that matches an input value, and when it is found, i would like to select on data with the highest match count and save it in a field, i am using cakephp.
here is what i have done so far:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $data = $this->Code->find('all',array(
            'conditions'=>array('Model.is_expired'=>0),
            'fields'=>array('Model.words'),

            ));

            $str = $this->request->data['Model']['words'] ;//the input value
            $sort_array=array();
            foreach($data as $value){
            $num = similar_text($value, $str);
            $sort_array[$value] = $num;
            }
         arsort($sort_array, SORT_REGULAR);
         $res = array_slice($sort_array,0,1);
         foreach($res as $key=>$value){
               return $key;
         }
            $this->request->data['Model']['invitee_1'] = $key;              
        }
        $this->Model->create();
        if ($this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Model has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Model could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

}
```

the table fields are:
id| words| new_word|

i would like to search the "words" fields for words that match the input value(from a form), and choose the word that has the highest match count and finally save it in the "new_word" field along side the form input which would be saved in the "words" field.

Comment: where id  `similar_text` function?

Comment: i don't get you u2460470 ..i used the similar_text function to match the two values.

Comment: it's hard to read your code as it is not indented in a readable way -- from what I understand, you return the $res in the preparation step (if there is any) and in that case you do not reach the saving, furthermore you `$this->request->data['Model']['invitee_1']` but `invitee_1 ` is not a field in you table